# Notification settings reset after reboot

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notifications, settings, reboot

I just bought a new smartphone and the new Android (6.0.1) has this peeking thing that really annoys me. I wanted to disable it, for example for WhatsApp, so I went to

`Settings -> Sound & notification -> App notifications -> Whatsapp -> Allow peeking (off)`

This solves the issue. The problem is that when I turn the device off and then turn it on again, these settings go back to default and the peeking is re-enabled without my doing anything.

Is there a way to permanently disable peeking?

**EDIT:**

I've found [this link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/howto-4-to-disable-heads-notifications-t3197660) and option 1 seemed very promising. However, I did that and it didn't work either. Still looking for the solution, though.

Comment: Wondering if your WhatsApp is on sd card ( not phone storage)- if so, reverting to phone storage and checking may help?

Comment: @beeshyams I've been looking this up on the Internet and that seems to be the problem for almost everyone. However, in my case, I have no apps on the SD Card, so this wouldn't be my case. It's really driving my crazy.

Comment: Is it only WhatsApp or with all apps?

Comment: @beeshyams I don't know if _all_ of them, but it appears to be a general problem, because I had turned peeking off for 6 or 7 apps and all of them reset after reboot.

Comment: @beeshyams I just checked again, and it is only WhatsApp that is having this issue. I was wrong before, I got confused with all the tests I did and they were all on normal because I had put them like that the last time.

Comment: Good you posted a solution +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally got it to work. I'm going to post the solution just in case someone is having the same problem. I did exactly as it is stated [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g5/help/peek-heads-notifications-reset-reboot-t3410571): just toggling another one of the other two options in the notification settings did the magic.